# How to make Flash project embedded in a desktop application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, autorun

I've made an interactive flash program and I want to make it an autorun CD which will be cross-platform for windows users. It should run without installing flash player.
I don't know how it's done. I've been told that it will be achieved by the use of adobe air , embedding and action script 3 !

I don't have a clue how it works! any help?

Comment: You need more than a clue - you need to read up on Adobe AIR. AIR is a  desktop 'runtime' player that allows, approximately, what you want to.  It is the alternative to the flash player, which is a browser plugin 'runtime' environment for Flash programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vastly over simplified, but here are the general steps.

1. Create a new document in Flash and choose "AIR for Desktop".
2. Build your application in the Flash document using ActionScript 3.
3. Publish as Adobe AIR, File>Publish. You will be required to enter many parameters, but selecting "Output as:" "AIR Package" will create an AIR file that will install and run the Flash project on Mac and Windows. The package also requires AIR to be installed on the user's computer which it will handle if necessary.
4. To make the CD auto run, you'll need to include an auto run file on the CD itself alongside the AIR file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really didn't know where to start, your answer made it clear! is it necessary to write some codes in order to check if flash player is installed? Or will adobe air take care of it?

Comment: AIR takes care of it. By default, AIR will also updates itself when new versions are available similar to the Flash player updating. You can make a total stand-alone app, no need AIR needed on the user's system, no AIR updating, but then you have to build your installer for each platform.

Comment: "but then you have to build your installer for each platform" what do you mean? my program doesn't need to be installed...

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Often, auto run is used to run an installer on a CD and prior to AIR 3.0, all AIR apps pretty much had to be installed. However, you can now create an AIR 3.0+ app that uses a captive runtime which creates a self-contained, executable application.

Comment: In air setting, there are 3 options.1-air package 2-windows installer 3-Application with runtime embedded. I tired all of them. Air package and windows installer provide an installer. My program doesn't require installation so I think the last option is what I need, but I have a problem with that. Although I have included some codes to view it in full screen mode, but after publishing with his option and running the exe file, it's not full screen! and one more thing, does this option provide running in every windows platform when flash player is not installed?

Comment: Did you turn off all the window options in the advance tab?The AIR captive runtime includes its own flash player so the system/browser flash player is not needed and the app will run on systems without flash player.

Comment: Yes, except for "visible". There is also another problem! I have imported a swf file in the project by the use of loader class, but it doesn't show when I publish it with this option! what should I do?

Comment: You might have to research the full screen issue. I don't know of any reason why AIR wouldn't display fullscreen when its run stand-alone. I have an app that does this, though its a captive runtime. The security is actually looser on the captive runtime so you should be able to do more. Did you include the swf file in the list of files on the first publish dialog panel? Does all this work ok if you do a standard AIR installer i.e. not captive runtime?

Comment: The swf loading problem is solved. For fullscreen mode,I've added this code in the first frame: fscommand("fullscreen","true");
fscommand("allowscale","false"); I'm not sure if anything else is needed !!

Comment: That's the older full screen command. The newer way is "stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; " Did you try that? I thought you had mentioned that you had set it up to run fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks, I found it out later.

Answer (score 0):

You need more than a clue - you need to read up on Adobe AIR. AIR is a desktop 'runtime' player that allows, approximately, what you want to.  It is the alternative to the Flash Player, which is a browser plugin 'runtime' environment for Flash programs. Actionscript3 is the language that you'll use (maybe you've used it already?) to program for flash player OR AIR.

If you've already created a program inside of Flash, check out the Publish Settings to target AIR instead of Flash Player.